# How can I get immediate, streaming, results from a query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Instead of interrupting an sql query that takes too long, can I make it return the results it has collected so far ?

```
select *
from giant_table
where complex_conditions;
```

Currently, I'm trying to eye-ball the runtime with limit:

```
...
limit 10; -- takes 30s
limit 100; -- takes 5min
limit ?; -- takes as long as my lunch
```

Of course, this is usually way off. Something like an anytime sql query that doesn't discard results when it is stopped would be great.

(I'm tagging this as sqlite, since that's what I'm currently using. But the dialect really isn't that important)

Comment: No, there is no Standard SQL feature to control when results are returned.

Comment: No.  A query has not "collected results" so far, in general.

Comment: In general (unless something in the execution plan uses a temporary b-tree), each row of the result is only calculated when requested.